# request.getParameter cannot be resolved in class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I`m writing a class to check a login and password in a MySQL database.
The filled form goes to a .jsp file and then I want to import that class in this .jsp to perform the operation.

The class goes like this:

```
import import java.sql.*;

public class TestQuery {   

    public void logging in() {

    String user = request.getParameter("user");
    String passwd = request.getParameter("passwd");
    Connection C = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?user=root&password=foo");

    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SQL QUERY");
    if (rs == NULL) {
        response.sendRedirect("LoginScreen.jsp");
    } else {
        switch (rs.getInt("id")) {
        case 1:
            response.sendRedirect("foo1.jsp");
            break;
        case 2:
            response.sendRedirect("foo2.jsp");
            break;
        case 3:
            response.sendRedirect("foo3.jsp");
            break;
        default:
            response.sendRedirect("LoginScreen.jsp");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But then I`m getting the message *request cannot be resolved*, *response cannot be resolved* etc.

What am I doing wrong? Is this the best way to perform this?

Comment: is this homework? reminds me how people wrote their web apps 10 years ago.

Answer (score 6):

Your class must extend [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html).

```
public class TestQuery extends HttpServlet {
    // ...
}
```

You must perform the job in either `doGet()` or `doPost()` depending on the request method. The `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` are available as method arguments.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // ...
}
```

Since this is rather trivial, you don't seem to have really read any JSP/Servlet book/tutorial. I strongly recommend to do so before continuing.

#### See also:

- [Our servlet wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains Hello World examples

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are instantiating this class and calling your method from a JSP.

request and response objects are automatically declared inside a JSP.  You need to pass in your request and response parameters into your method from the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28961/genlovw.htm), it means that you can use `request` in your jsp page (or servlets via implemenatation HTTpServelt and using doPost or get methods ), but cannot use in other classes!

> Implicit Objects
>
> JSP technology makes available to any JSP page a set of implicit
>   objects. **These are Java objects that are created automatically by the
>   Web container and that allow interaction with the underlying servlet
>   environment.**
>
> The implicit objects listed immediately below are available. For
>   information about methods available with these objects, refer to the
>   Sun Microsystems Javadoc for the noted classes and interfaces.
>
> page
>
> This is an instance of the JSP page implementation class and is
>   created when the page is translated. The page implementation class
>   implements the interface javax.servlet.jsp.HttpJspPage. Note that page
>   is synonymous with this within a JSP page.
>
> **request**
>
> This represents an HTTP request and is an instance of a class that
>   implements the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest interface, which
>   extends the javax.servlet.ServletRequest interface.